# Few queries in UML diagrams

Tags: uml

I have following questions regarding to  UML diagrams:

1) I have one Game application in C# consisting of 3 games namely crosswords,sudocu n scribble
& I have only 3 classes belonging to each game then:

- In the class diagram will only those 3 classes come? But they don't have any associativity among them
- And The states in the state diagram will be pause,running,stopped respectively? or do I need to specify the states according to game

2)I have an application in java which allows user to do one thing  at a time by selecting a option from the options(I have used JTabbedPane) available then:

- Do I need to draw an activity diagram for each of those options available?

Comment: UML diagrams are a tool to aid understanding. It seems like the answer to both your questions is "do whatever makes it easiest for another programmer to understand".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a state or activity diagram at the root of each class in the class diagram. You will be able to model this extension.
[image]
<sub>(source: [forum-omondo.com](http://www.forum-omondo.com/state_diagram_extension.png))</sub>

Comment: The forum, that the image is linked to, seems to provide the same image result for any image link now (it is an ad for a site).